# Implicit differentiation of an equation of a hyperbola

Tags: implicit-differentiation

Prove that an equation of the tangent line to the graph of the hyperbola : 
$(x^2/a^2)  -  (y^2/b^2) = 1$

at the point ($x_0$, $y_0$) is

$x x_0/a^2 - y y_0/b^2 = 1$  (1)

---

I implicitly differentiated the equation and then found the gradient by substituting in the points to get the gradient ( $b^2x_0/a^2y_0$) and use the points, plug it into $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$
But I don't know how to rearrange it to get to (1). Please help me!

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you showed you work

Comment: So I differentiated   $(x^2/a^2) - (y^2/b^2) = 1$       with respect to x, this was so that I could find the gradient as the question asks to prove that an equation of the tangent line is..... After I implicitly differentiate I get $b^2x/a^2y$. As they have given me the points $(x_0,y_0)$ I sub it into the gradient I have found and that gives me the $(b^2x_0/a^2y_0)$ and now as its asking for equation of a line i sub it into the line formula $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$, using the gradient and the point I have. I  however, am not able to get the equation (1) stated in the question @IsaacBrowne

Comment: I saw that. What I meant was showing the process of your substitution. When writing future questions, make sure to include all of your work. This will help your questions get answered better and faster!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align} 
y-y_0 & = \frac{b^2x_0}{a^2y_0}(x-x_0) 
\\ a^2y_0(y-y_0)& = (b^2x_0)(x-x_0) 
\\ a^2y_0y-a^2y_0^2& = b^2x_0x-b^2x_0^2 
\\ b^2x_0^2 -a^2y_0^2& = b^2x_0x-a^2y_0y
\end{align}
$(x_0,y_0)$ satisfaces that $\frac{x_0^2}{a^2}-\frac{y_0^2}{b^2}=1$ doing the operations, $b^2x_0^2 -a^2y_0^2=a^2b^2$, then:
\begin{align} 
\\ b^2x_0^2 -a^2y_0^2& = b^2x_0x-a^2y_0y
\\ a^2b^2& = b^2x_0x-a^2y_0y
\\ 1& = \frac{xx_0}{a^2}-\frac{yy_0}{b^2}
\end{align}